# which one is better - SchedulerExecutorService or Quartz api

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduledexecutorservice

I want to run a task after specified delay and at given intervals.

If I use SchedulerExecutorService, since it uses thread so task execution is getting delayed a little bit.

I cannot afford delay in execution.How can I make it run at exact specified interval?

What about Quartz library? This library would solve the purpose?

As I am not very much aware of Quartz library, I would also like to know what is the difference between SchedulerExecutorService and Quartz api?

Note:

[I have also asked the question on why is it getting delayed using SchedulerExecutorService.Please refer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371319/scheduleatfixedrate-not-starting-the-task-at-specified-delay)

Comment: Why is it getting delayed? Quartz is using thread pools as well.

Comment: @Stefan I have edited the question. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: "I cannot afford delay in execution." Does this mean you have real-time-requirements?

Comment: @Fildor Actually the execution of this task will let the third party to do their task. So its important that this task should run at the exact time.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, if you need high availability (you want to have more than one machine to execute the task so that tasks are run even when a machine or app. instance fails), then use Quartz. Otherwise use ScheduledExecutorService.